# Outlook MAPI throws error creating Teams Meeting from calendar

Tags: c++, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, mapi

I have my own plugin written for Outlook MAPI in C++.
We have our own server code and client interacts with it using SOAP Req/Resp.

Now when we have Microsoft Teams installed on the PC. If someone opens Outlook, and goes to Calendar, it shows "New Teams Meeting" button on "Home" ribbon. If someone clicks it. It opens the new meeting compose button but on shows message box with error "We couldn't schedule the meeting. Please try again later". Once we click OK on that message box, it closes the compose windows and returns to the main windows.

But it works perfectly when someone follows path : Ribbon Home->New Items->Meeting. Now it opens new meeting compose windows. Now on the new meeting compose windows Ribbon Meeting->Teams Meeting and it perfectly works fine by adding Teams Meeting URL at the bottom in body.

Any idea what could be the problem? What's missing there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying it works fine if your addin is not installed?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, Yes it works fine when addin is not installed in both the cases mentioned above. But even in case of my addin installed, it works fine when someone creates new teams meeting by Ribbon Home->New Items->Meeting now on new page "Teams Meeting". It gives problem when we click Ribbon Home->New Teams Meeting.

Comment: Try to comment out most of your addin functionality and bring it back a few lines at  time until the problem reappears.

Comment: Let me do that. Thanks @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko any idea how to understand from which line Teams Meeting Dialog is coming? It's not coming from my code. But unable to trace the line which is responsible for it as it's Outlook code and not our code.

Comment: I don't know. That is what you need to find out - after commenting out various parts of your code, see when the problem stops manifesting itself. Then figure out what your commented code does.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this problem is related to the Teams add-in, see [Teams in Outlook: We Couldn’t Schedule the Meeting](https://www.technipages.com/teams-in-outlook-we-couldnt-schedule-the-meeting#:%7E:text=This%20error%20may%20occur%20because,can%20schedule%20your%20meetings%20now.).

Comment: I checked and it's not related to Teams add-in.

Comment: How did you check that? I see the whole paragraph in your post about the Teams add-in in Outlook.

Comment: I mean to say, I followed the fixes described there but it's about Teams Add-in not appearing and all. Which I followed but still it's throwing the same error when I go to calendar and click on New Teams Meeting. Looks like something wrong with either code of my plugin or Teams Add-in itself has some problem. I'll have to search more on net.

Comment: Try to comment the code in your add-in, so returning back line-by-line you may find the cause if it belongs to your add-in.